# What is the difference between lm() and rlm()?

Tags: r, regression

I just found "Robust Fitting of Linear Models" `rlm()` [function in the `MASS` library](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-47/topics/rlm).

I would like to know the difference between this function and the standard linear regression function, `lm()`.

Could someone give me a short explanation?

Answer (score 17):

It (`rlm`) is for robust linear models.  It is describe in Venables & Ripley.  However, details of the robust calculations would not fit in a "short answer": you need to look into several papers by Ripley, Tukey, and others.

It a form of [robust regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression#Least_squares_alternatives) that uses [M-estimators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator).

Check out this paper by Ripley for more information: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/StatMeth/Robust.pdf

Comment: You can also see bits and pieces of the discussion in the relevant book (Venables and Ripley MASS) on Google books: http://books.google.com/books?id=974c4vKurNkC&lpg=PP1&dq=venables%20ripley&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q=rlm&f=false -- if you want the whole thing you need to buy the book or find it at the library ... **very** briefly, robust regression downweights the effects of outliers on the analysis.

Answer (score 7):

lm function uses Ordinary Least Squares(OLS) method for reducing the residuals.
whereas rlm function uses M-estimators. 
OLS is very sensitive to outliers, M-estimation method is not.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:
In `rlm()`, points are not treated equally. The weight of each point would be adjusted in an iterative process. `rlm()` is less sensitive to outliers, as outliers will get reduced weight.

If you want a short answer for the math, I suggest [an article provided by Johns Hopkins Bloomberg School of Public Health](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~iruczins/teaching/jf/ch13.pdf)